# Why do I have to double click to change the relief of my button object ? (tkinter)

Tags: python, methods, tkinter, bind, double-click

Good afternoon!

Why do I have to double click to change the relief of my button object ?

In my method bind, my first parameter is Button-1, I don't understand...

Here is my code, thank you in advance.

```
from tkinter import *

def sunken(event):
    button = event.widget # détecte le bouton sur lequel on clique
    button['relief'] = 'sunken' # changement de relief

root = Tk()

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        myButton = Button(root, text='', relief='raised')
        myButton.grid(row=i, column=j)
        myButton.bind("<Button-1>", sunken)

root.mainloop()
```

Python 3.x

I apologize for my english, I'm french...

Comment: I don't think I should put this as an answer as I am not certain but perhaps it has something to do with the fact that when a `Button` is clicked its `relief` is changed to `SUNKEN` automatically by `tkinter` and then back to normal again. I noticed also that you don't need to just click twice, but if the two clicks on the same button are something like more than 10 seconds apart, it doesn't sink. This leads me to believe that the two `relief` configs are conflicting in this timeframe.

Comment: I agree, it's something about the button's default behavior. If you replace your buttons with Entry fields, it works as expected. You might consider that a button is, by default, bound to a left-click event, so using a command to callback your function within the button might serve you well, ie, Button(root, text='', command=sunken). Of course, you'd need to change how your buttons are generated or come up with some other work around to pass the button you want changed to the function. Good luck!

Comment: @Alex, thank you, you have put the bug in my ear, I'm posting the good response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of my question

```
from tkinter import *

def sunken(event):
    button = event.widget # detecte le bouton sur lequel on clique
    button['relief'] = 'sunken' # changement de relief

root = Tk()

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        myButton = Button(root, text='', state='disabled')
        myButton.grid(row=i, column=j)
        myButton.bind("<Button-1>", sunken)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? I don't understand. Are you saying that disabling the button solves your problem?

Comment: @Bryan, yes, I should clarified que my buttons are disable. the default is NORMAL for my buttons and it works...

Comment: @Bryan, when my buttons are disable, the only event is taken into account, I think.